# How to set cell accessoryType as String, IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, string, uitableview

Some of my tableview cells has arrows, 
I set arrows by

`cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;`

But In one of the table view cells I want to display a simple string or text rather then an arrow

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Version"]){
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}
```

How can I display a string at the most right side of the tableview cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting `cell.accessoryType`, you can set `self.accessoryView` to any `UIView`, for example to a `UILabel` that you create with the text.

Answer (score 0):

Use `accessoryView` property of the cell:

```
UILabel * disclosureLabel = //create your UILabel
cell.accessoryView = disclosureLabel;
[disclosureLabel release];
```